# What is the meaning of the four parameters in CallSnapshotEx, dwParams[4]?

Tags: windows-ce

This structure is used to store extended information about stack frames.

```
typedef struct _CallSnapshotEx {
  DWORD dwReturnAddr;
  DWORD dwFramePtr;
  DWORD dwCurProc;
  DWORD dwParams[4];
} CallSnapshotEx;
```

Does anybody know what dwParams is about?

Comment: It's not clear from the docs but I suspect it's an array of pointers to the parameters sent into the function at the given point in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The structure `CallSnapshotEx` gets filled by the function call `GetThreadCallStack` with `STACKSNAP_EXTENDED_INFO` flag. The `dwParams` contains the parameters for the function. I guess it is just a standard convention to use four parameters. Because, if you observe the documentation of another related structure `CallSnapshot3`, the number of parameters is four. I don't think there might be any other strong reason behind it other than the convention that a minimum of four dwords must always be allocated.